# How to Create menu top and bottom both of them in Android?

Tags: android, menubar

I wanna create a menu that be seen when clicked on the center of screen like Aldiko.

[image]

I've tested `PopupWindow` for create menu items but I didn't any solution for **trackbar**.

Are there any solutions?

Comment: You'd need a custom implementation. Don't know how much luck you're going to have with trying to find an out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Default Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) you can create Bottom or TOP layout. So you cant used this. But you can create your own layouts. Align one layout to top & second to bottom. Initially did `INVISIBLE` both layouts, when you click on center then `VISIBLE` both layouts.

Comment: I've get what you said. but I don't know how can I develop Android menu(Especially seekBar). Could you show an example?

Comment: I studied this page. As I said, How can I extend menu. I don't have any idea for inserting a seekbar into menu and set items width/height?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split ActionBar for getting something like you want. The only repercussion of using it will be the look in different screen modes (portrait and landscape). Your action items will align themselves as per the available screen space. Let me know if you are looking for some code for doing it with ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FrameLayout` and put the main app layout on back frame and menu (with transparent background) on the top frame. Initial set the visibility of the menu layout to invisible so you app main layout would only be visible. Now when you clicks on the main layout just change the visibility to visible, when user press again set the top layout again to invisible.